# Updating variables inside js template literals

Tags: javascript, html

I have 1 string named **a** which stores large html element with js template literals by calling objects property . I am keeping those element in my **div id hello**. Now I want to update data inside js template literal  when I change  objects property  without keeping elements of a in div again.

```
my code:-


var object = {name:'alisha', age:18 , count:1000};

var a = `<div class="nav">
              <span>name:</span><span>${object.name}<span><br>
              <span>age:</span><span>${object.age}<span><br>
              <span>count:</span><span>${object.count}<span><br>
              <input type="text">
         </div>`;

  var el = document.getElementById('hello');
  el.innerHTML = a;

 var replace_count = 0;
 setInterval(function(){
     replace_count = replace_count + 1;
     var object.count = replace_count;
 },2000)
```

Yes I have alternative idea of doing this but I can't follow those idea

My Ideas:-

> I can give id or class to each span containing js template literals.
>
> I can keep all the elements of variable a by updating objects property in div of id hello.

Please give me idea how can I do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to place the object and the string within a function to get this to work.

```js
function doReplace(count) {
  var object = {name:'alisha', age:18 , count};

  var a = `<div class="nav">
              <span>name:</span><span>${object.name}<span><br>
              <span>age:</span><span>${object.age}<span><br>
              <span>count:</span><span>${object.count}<span><br>
              <input type="text">
         </div>`;

    var el = document.getElementById('hello');
    el.innerHTML = a;
}

 var replace_count = 0;
 doReplace(replace_count);
 setInterval(function(){
     replace_count = replace_count + 1;
     doReplace(replace_count);
 },200)
```

```html
<div id="hello"></div>
```

I change the time to 200ms instead of 2s so it is easier to see.

But the string literals must be recreated each time. It is a literal, not a template.

If you don't want to replace the entire `innerHTML` every time, then you need to set the innerHTML once and then change the `textContent` of the correct span during each step of the interval.

But, as I said above, these are not really templates and the ES6 name of **template literal** is misleading. There is no binding in vanilla JavaScript and Template Literals are a one time generation. So you need to either regenerate the literal after the data changes or just change the `innerHTML` or `textContent` of a specific element.

**UPDATE**

> You must understand that vanilla JavaScript does not have built in data binding. Template Literals are really just a simplification of string concatenation. But they are not bindable templates.

You can always look into any of the multiple of template tools out there. If you don't want something as heavy as React, Vue or Angular then you can look into things like Rivets, Simulacra, knockout or any other of the many small data binding libraries out there.

```js
var object = {name:'alisha', age:18 , count:0};

function render(obj) {
  var binders = document.querySelectorAll('[bind]');
  binders.forEach(
    (el) => {
      var field = el.getAttribute('bind');
      if (field && (obj[field] !== undefined)) {
        el.innerHTML = obj[field];
      }
    }
  );
}

var replace_count = 0;
render(object);
setInterval(function(){
  object.count++;
  render(object);
},200)
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <div>name: <span bind="name"></div>
  <div>age: <span bind="age"></div>
  <div>count: <span bind="count"></div>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

This is a simple binding library I just wrote. It is under 300 bytes. It probably needs some enhancements, but it shows that you can create a *very simple* binding library.

If these answers don't help then please describe **why** they don't help. I can help if you don't describe why.

Comment: Intervalia I have already mentioned that idea. But this idea don't works for me.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Here this simple function do everything.

```
const getTemplateByInterpolatingParams = (templateHTML, placeholders) => {
  try {
    const names = Object.keys(placeholders);
    const values = Object.values(placeholders);
    return new Function(...names, `return \`${templateHTML}\`;`)(...values);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error in template interpolation', error);
    return error;
  }
};
```

Pass your template with `template literals` and object with same keys

Answer (score -4):

If you will use jQuery, it is easy:

HTML

```
<span>count:</span><span class="count"></span>
```

JS

```
var replace_count = 0;
setInterval(function(){
    $('.nav span.count','#hello').text(replace_count++);
}, 2000);
```

This will change the data in all span.count in div#hello every 2 sec.
If you render **${object.count}**, than it is a normal Text, or you use view.js or angular with special template-engine.

test it on fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/chrobaks/r2a1anw6/